# Escaping characters in javascript for mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am having some issues inserting objects into a mysql table. One is a google lat/lng object (using VARCHAR):

```
JSON.stringify(coordinates)

[-90.02532485,35.04651167]
```

Also some url's:

```
 mysqlEscape(aurl);

function mysqlEscape(stringToEscape){
    return stringToEscape
        .replace("\\", "\\\\")
        .replace("\'", "\\\'")
        .replace("\"", "\\\"")
        .replace("\n", "\\\n")
        .replace("\r", "\\\r")
        .replace("\x00", "\\\x00")
        .replace("\x1a", "\\\x1a");
};

 error on http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ci5x4CZXAAAZCZc.jpg
```

How can insert these?

Comment: You added backticks? What exactly did you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: Backticks are *only* for table/field names, **not** values.  String values use single or double quotes.

Comment: Is this JavaScript running in a browser or on the server (node.js)?

Comment: I read another post that said it might fix it. Will remove. Running nodejs.

Comment: How are you attempting to insert this object?  What's your SQL query/code?

Answer (score 0):

To escape strings in JS you will be better off using `encodeURIComponent` function rather than rolling your own solution.

```
console.log(encodeURIComponent('http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ci5x4CZXAAAZCZc.jpg'));

// output -> http%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FCi5x4CZXAAAZCZc.jpg
```

For more details look at the `encodeURIComponent` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).